# Fetch data not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hello I'm trying to get data from the database table called 'werknemer' and echo it in a view page but I'm getting these 2 errors somehow:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Addwerknemer::$Werknemer_model
>
> Filename: controllers/Addwerknemer.php
>
> Line Number: 10
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\controllers\Addwerknemer.php
>   Line: 10
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once
>
> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>   Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function fetch_data_werknemer() on null
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\controllers\Addwerknemer.php
>
> Line Number: 10
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once
>   This is my model fetch function:

```
<?php

class Werknemer_model extends CI_model  

    {
        public function fetch_data_werknemer()
        $query = $this->db->get('werknemer');
        //Haal alle gegevens uit werknemer tabel en sla op in $query variabele
        return $query;
    }

    }


?>
```

This is my controller (Addwerknemer.php):

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Main_model');
        $data['werknemer_data'] = $this->Werknemer_model->fetch_data_werknemer();
        $this->load->view('addwerknemer', $data);
    }
```

And this is how I'm trying to echo it in the view:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Naam</th>
                    <th>Wachtwoord</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                if($werknemer_data->num_rows() > 0)
                {
                    foreach($werknemer_data->result() as $row)
                    {
                ?>
                 <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row->werknemer_id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->naam; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->wachtwoord; ?></td>
                 </tr>
                <?php
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <!--Als er geen werknemers zijn echo dit bericht--> 
                        <td colspan="3"> Geen data gevonden </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </table>
```

I just can't figure out why I'm getting those 2 errors.
I hope someone can help me out
Any kind of help is appreciated, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not load the correct model. You have load werknemer_model, Example:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('werknemer_model');
        $data['werknemer_data'] = $this->werknemer_model->fetch_data_werknemer();
        $this->load->view('addwerknemer', $data);
    }
```

Comment: @Mulet LPease view this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606130/table-not-fetching-data-from-database-in-codeigniter?noredirect=1#comment101669330_57606130