# Table not fetching data from database in codeigniter..?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

Model

```
function allDocs()
    {
        $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('docs')->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Controller

```
public function viewauction()
    {
        $this->load->model('Crud_model');
        $data['query'] = $this->Crud_model->allDocs();   
        $this->load->view('index', $data);
    }
```

View

```
<tbody>

                  <?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
                  <tr>   
                      <td><?php echo $row->doc_id; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row->RefNo; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row->MyNo; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row->RegNo; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row->LetterDate; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row->LetterReceivedFrom; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row->Subject; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row->Title; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row->Officer_InCharge; ?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

I tried this..but I dont get any data for "query".

Error Shows
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: query

Filename: views/index.php

Line Number: 277

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\1\application\views\index.php
Line: 277
Function: _error_handler

I did initialize controller in index too..
please help me.

Comment: what returns `print_r($data['query'])`?

Comment: what is the value of ```$data['query']```

Comment: where can we use this to print..in view file? 
If so it shows nothing..
My database configurations are correct because i use a form already to insert data to it..now i get this problem when I fetch data to be displayed in a table

Comment: looks like your query doesn't return any result....

Comment: Table contains data.. why then query doesnt return any result..?

Comment: Do I have to load write controller codes inside controller index..?
Nopz...it too doesnt wor.. :/

Comment: check your database configuration, and did you connect to the database? either in autoload or with: `$this->load->database();`

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','table');
In Autoload - COnfig

Comment: Inserting works..so there is no issue with db connection

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using data['query'] you have only one value, 
try this

```
public function viewauction()
    {
        $this->load->model('Crud_model');
        $query' = $this->Crud_model->allDocs();   
        $this->load->view('index', $query);
    }
```

I think it helps you

Comment: ooo sorry did you see my code there is error after $query i left '

Answer (score 0):

You can try This code hope it will help you.

Change In Model:

```
function allDocs()
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('docs')->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

to

```
function allDocs()
{
    $query = $this->db->select('doc_id, RefNo, MyNo, RegNo, LetterDate, LetterReceivedFrom, Subject, Title, Officer_InCharge')->from('docs')->get();
    $result = $query->result();        
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Message: Undefined variable: query :/ 
Still its unsuccessful..i am so confused. Why Query is not defined it fetches $result isnt it..?

Comment: Do I have to run $this->viewauction() under index function..?

Comment: so you can try what you have fetch call that data

Comment: like          $this->db->select('doc_id, RefNo, MyNo, RegNo, LetterDate, LetterReceivedFrom, Subject, Title, Officer_InCharge')->from('docs')->get();

Comment: return $query->result();

Comment: try this it should help you

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this is because `$data` has not been defined before you used it. Try this:-

```
public function viewauction()
{
    $this->load->model('Crud_model');
    $data = [
        'query' => $this->Crud_model->allDocs(),
    ];
    $this->load->view('index', $data);
}
```

Comment: :/ 
Message: Undefined variable: data..
Still the Fetch result variable is been undefined..why :/

Comment: Do I have to run $this->viewauction() under index function..?

Answer (score 0):

You should load the controller whenever the specific view is loaded.

```
public function dashboard()
{
        $this->load->model('Crud_model');
        $data = $this->Crud_model->allDocs();
        $this->load->view('index',['data'=> $data]); 
}
```

Here, Dashboard is the controller function in which I load the page in which I have to pass the data from database. I have written codes to fetch data through model in viewauction() method here.
Thereby I failed to load this controller whenever I load the view page.

My code for fetching is all correct, and only thing I missed was that I didnt load in correct View Page.

Moreover I changed this line as well

```
$this->load->view('index',['data'=> $data]);
```

Thank You Guys for all your suggestions.